# docker - libudev: udev_has_devtmpfs: name_to_handle_at on /dev: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, docker

I doing Docker tests about using apps with GUI. SublimeText,Eclipse,Hangout and others apps good working but in this case i try install popcorntime app in to docker container using Debian image and when i execute the app show me some errors. Sorry, but i'm new in Docker world and would like know how to fix this problem for future occasions.

First, I execute to docker container of next form:

docker run -ti -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY --shm-size=1024m --memory 512m --device /dev/snd popcorntime bash

Next, into contaniner:

root@1cc4aea76556:/opt/popcorntime# ./Popcorn-Time

libudev: udev_has_devtmpfs: name_to_handle_at on /dev: Operation not permitted [59:1106/211526:WARNING:x11_util.cc(315)] X failed to attach to shared memory segment 262145 [59:1106/211529:INFO:CONSOLE(120)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: pageOptions is not defined", source: http://app.time4popcorn.eu/?uid=17F98CC7FD403488DA7B5E1D6989EE2C&register_date=1478465906&version=0.3.0&os=linux&r=0.025844353018328547 (120) [59:1106/211529:INFO:CONSOLE(120)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: pageOptions is not defined", source: http://app.time4popcorn.eu/?uid=17F98CC7FD403488DA7B5E1D6989EE2C&register_date=1478465906&version=0.3.0&os=linux&r=0.025844353018328547 (120) [59:1106/211529:ERROR:crash_handler_host_linux.cc(380)] Failed to write crash dump for pid 79 Cannot upload crash dump: cannot alloc [59:1106/211529:ERROR:breakpad_linux.cc(1225)] crash dump file written to /tmp/chromium-renderer-minidump-b10e73ec0d1694fc.dmp

Please, someone that me orient for know how to execute this app using docker container???....

Answer (score 5):

[Docker Seccomp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/) default profile disabled a system call that your container is calling.
As quick and dirty solution, try running the container with additional option after docker run

```
--security-opt seccomp=unconfined
```

This way you run a container without the default seccomp profile. Then it should be better to use a custom profile putting in the white list the systemn call your container needs.

Comment: ok, now i try with the flag --security-opt seccomp=unconfined and only hidden  the first error but the others errors persist and the app not working

Comment: You pass an empty environment variable DISPLAY; I don't know if it's correct. May be useful to look at some already done images and dockerfiles from the web, e.g https://hub.docker.com/r/jerivas/popcorntime/  . Sorry, but I can't help you further about popcorntime.

Comment: The environment variable DISPLAY is good because i tested some apps for example: SublimeText, Eclipse and it's working. Now, i was try with hub.docker.com/r/jerivas/popcorntime . but not work.